# C++ How to keep track of local variables/objects

Tags: variables, local, draw, children, actor

Firstly, i am sorry if the title does not properly describe my problem, but i could not think of a better one. =/

I am trying to make a game where all entities that I need to draw on the screen are children of an Actor class.

The actor class has a virtual function called "**virtual void drawMe()**" that is overridden by the children to specify how it should be drawn.

Ergo, at the end of the game loop, I want to draw all actors. I created  a "**vector allActors**" to help me with this and every time I create a new actor I do this: "**allActors.push_back( &newActor )**". So far so good (I think).

To draw them at the end of the loop I iterate through all elements in allActors and call "**allActors[i]->drawMe()**" for each one.

But I discovered that this method will not work for actors that I created locally, like the bullets created when the character shoots (they are created inside an if statement).
I think it is because while I save the address of the bullets in the allActors vector, the actors themselves are destroyed after the if statement ends, so it's an address to nothing.

example:

```
if ( characterShot == true)
{
    Bullet newBullet;
    allActors.push_back( &newBullet );
    characterShot = false;
}
```

I have no idea of how to do this in a way that it works, because I can only create the bullet actors IF the character shoots!

Please help me figure out a better and more functional way to do what I want.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I like the thought that you put into this question. It is a beginners question, but I only wish all beginners would think it over that carefully and take the time to ask the question patiently too. You'll get there soon enough!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allocate the object dynamically:

```
allActors.push_back(new Bullet);
```

Note that the lifetime management will be a genuine nightmare; you should make the container elements some sort of smart pointer (ideally `std::unique_ptr<Bullet>` or some suitable base class).

Comment: hehe - always the optimist. Not a nightmare... if all pointers are owned by the vector, simply remember to delete items upon removal (and removing all items before destructing the vector). This can be a (error-prone) chore, so smart pointers help a lot.

Comment: @sehe: Yes, perhaps :-) Given that the OP doesn't seem to be 100% at home with the notion of dynamic vs automatic storage, I was letting my imagination run wild... but you're right, it's entirely possible that her code is otherwise entirely fine!

Comment: Thank you guys for the reply, I had never used dynamic object allocation before. IT WORKED! I am still gonna figure out what you guys are saying about smart pointers though... But I'm gonna get there! =)
Note: I am a HE. lol

Answer (score 0):

You're right in your assumption that you're pushing an address to a local object that then goes out of scope. Doing this should cause your application to be quite unstable.

Allocate the object on the heap instead, using a smart pointer that keeps track of the lifetime of the object for you:

```
allActors.push_back(tr1::shared_ptr<Bullet>(new Bullet));
```

This gives you another problem: You have to remove the bullet from the `allActors` array once it hits the target.